# Why does std::distance produce a negative result?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

The code is as follow:

```
int B[] = {3,5};
int C[] = {4,5};
cout << std::distance(B,C);
```

The output is:

```
-4
```

Can anyone explain why is this?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. `distance` works with iterators to single containers.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. There's nothing reliable to explain.

Comment: Probably you have wrong understanding of `std::distance` ?

Comment: From the usage, I guess the mistaken understanding was that it would calculate the Euclidean distance between points specified by their Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `distance(first, last)` function tells you how many items are between the iterator at `first` and `last`. Note that pointers are iterators, random-access iterators to be specific. So the distance between one pointer and another is their difference, as defined by `operator-`.

So your question boils down to "How many `ints` are there between the `int` pointed to by `B` and the `int` pointed to by `C`?

`distance` dutifully subtracts the pointers and tells you.

The trick is that `distance` is supposed to be applied to iterators from the same container. Your code does not live up to that promise. The compiler is free to place the `B` and `C` arrays wherever it pleases, hence the result you see is meaningless. Like many things in C++, it's up to you to ensure that you're using `distance` properly. If you don't, you'll get undefined behavior, where the language makes no guarantees what will happen.

Comment: one more question, is there a way to show it is undefined behavior?

Comment: You look at the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`std::distance(__first, __last)` is designed to generalize pointer arithmetic, it returns a value `n` such that `__first + n = __last`. 
 for your case, the arguments are pointers of `int*`, in terms of iteration, they are random accessed iterators. the implementation simply returns a value of `__last - __first`: 
simply `(int*)C - (int*)B`.